# Pause Excel macro while Windows is locked

Tags: vba, excel, pause

I have a macro which runs an SQL query, which triggers a long slow recalculation of the spreadsheet based on the new data. When it finishes I've used `application.speech` to alert me if certain conditions have been met; all this works fine. But:

As I said, the recalculation can take quite a while, so I sometimes lock Windows and go do something else while I wait. Does anyone know of a way to pause the macro so that it doesn't run the last few lines (i.e. the audio alerts) until Windows is unlocked?

Comment: Google is a marvelous tool...search for:  vba check if windows is locked   and you get:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/646623-check-if-system-locked-unlocked-using-vba.html

Comment: One day I found something like that: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Ran that in a new blank worksheet: no problem. Added it to my existing sheet: "Compile error: Variable not defined" for "system". Why the difference?

Comment: Assuming you mean the code found at the link I provided, I can't explain 'difference' without knowing exactly all the steps you took for each test. I do know why you get the compile error: 'System' is not defined. I simply defined a string variable named System and then ran the code. You would need to place a call to 'Check_If_Locked' just before you want to alert the user, and if locked, go into a wait-state (i.e. use the timer).

Comment: Yes, that code. Defined the variable and all was well. So how, when I tried it first as the only code in a new, blank workbook, did it run without?

Comment: The short answer is Option Explicit. Your program I suspect has it - and so objected to an undeclared variable. The blank workbook didn't and so wouldn't object to the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call Application.speech you could check if the system is locked and if it is locked you repeat the check every minute until it is unlocked.
Code if a system is locked

```
Sub SystemLocked()

    Do While Check_If_Locked = "Locked"
        Application.Wait TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Code for Check_If_Locked can be found here
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/646623-check-if-system-locked-unlocked-using-vba.html